# Javascript array or Google Charts view.setColumns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know the topic Sorry for title. anybody who understand my question could edit my question title.

Script:

```
// I get checkboxes values with using this function
var myValues = $(".filter:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

alert("[0," + myValues + "]");
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(new google.visualization.DataTable(evalledData, 0.5));
view.setColumns([0, myValues]); // I pass the checked values.
```

When I write above code I got this error: `"type" must be specified`

If I wrote `view.setColumns([0, 1,2,3,4]);` It works.

alert output : `[0,1,2,3,4]` so there is no difference between two usage.

Why I got this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

```
// This function returns string array. 
var myValues = $(".filter:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

// I converted it an Int array.
$.each(myValues, function (index, value) {
    arrayAll.push(parseInt(value, 10));
    //alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```